# How to pass a symbol through rails routes specified through 'resources'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have this set of routes

```
  resources :flatfiles do
    collection do
      delete :custom_destroy
    end
  end
```

And I would like to all of the routes to include `:key`

E.g. `get 'flatfiles/:key' => 'flatfiles#index'`

I could specify each route individually (like the get action above), but is there a way to do them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:path`

```
  resources :flatfiles, path: 'flatfiles/:key' do
    collection do
      delete :custom_destroy
    end
  end
```

That will prefix all sub routes with `:key`